# Firebug or IEDevtoolbaar styling inline or from stylesheet

Tags: css, firebug, styles

Is Firebug or IEDevtoolbar capable of distinction between Inline / External stylesheet styling? If not, is it possible to write a tool that is capable to distinct inline styling from styles from a stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug can do that

In the style panel, it shows Element.style, and all styles applied from stylesheets, with the overridden styles crossed out

Answer (score 1):

Firebug, WebKit Inspector, and IE's DebugBar can do that - they generally keep inline styles in one group and stylesheet rules in another.